# Connecting files like columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, files

I have this command:

```
for file in file??.txt; do awk -f vypis_z_dcout.awk "$file" > "$file".csv; done
```

The result is a column of numbers from each file and I want to connect results  from all files in one file like its columns. How to add to this command?

```
paste <(cat f.csv) <(cat f1.csv) <(cat f2.csv) <(cat f3.csv) <(cat f4.csv) .... insert "$file".csv ... > out.csv
```

Or how to get a file where in the first column will be file01.csv, in the second file02.csv and so on? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying, you start out with a set of files with names along the lines of:

```
file01.txt
file02.txt
file03.txt
```

You then process each one of those text files in turn with `awk`, which produces a column of data for each file processed.  So in this hypothetical directory, there are now 6 files:

```
file01.txt
file02.txt
file03.txt
file01.txt.csv
file02.txt.csv
file03.txt.csv
```

And the last 3 files are the results of the `awk` program.

To paste the CSV files produced in the previous step together into one CSV file with as many columns as there are files generated in the previous step, use:

```
paste -d '[DELIMITER]' file??.txt.csv > out.csv
```

Replace `[DELIMITER]` in the above code with the character you want to use as the delimiter in the resulting CSV file.  For example, if `file01.txt.csv` contained the following data:

```
1
2
3
```

...and `file02.txt.csv` contained the following data:

```
4
5
6
```

...and `file03.txt.csv` contained the following data:

```
7
8
9
```

...then `paste -d ';' file??.txt.csv > out.csv` would fill the file "out.csv" with:

```
1;4;7
2;5;8
3;6;9
```